# Javascript only running in admin panel, not on other pages

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a simple js file that I think may be the problem, (that or my theme). I want it to load on all pages. It simply dims the page over a period of time.

```
var Color= new Array(31);
Color[31] = "eaebec";
Color[30] = "E8E8E8";
Color[29] = "E0E0E0";
Color[28] = "D8D8D8";
Color[27] = "D0D0D0";
```

etc.

```
function fadeIn(where) {
if (where >= 1) {
document.bgColor="#" + Color[where] ;
where -= 1;
setTimeout("fadeIn("+where+")", 600);
} 
}

function Go()
{
fadeIn(31);
}
window.onload=Go;
```

When I plug the following code into my functions.php file

```
function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('fadetoblack', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fadetoblack.js', array('jquery'));
}    

    add_action('init', 'load_scripts');
```

I only get the desired action within the admin dashboard, not on the other pages. At the top of those pages I get

```
function load_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
   wp_enqueue_script('fadetoblack', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fadetoblack.js', array('jquery')); 
} 
add_action('init', 'load_scripts');
```

written at the top of the screen. For the main page nothing shows up and the .js file is not in my resources using Chrome to inspect. For individual pages the text appears at top and the file appears in resources with Chrome during inspection.

I am using the K2 theme. Wordpress  3.3.1.

Here is a pastebin link to the functions.php file

http://pastebin.com/q2TavVdV

Here is the pastebin link to the fadetoblack.js file

http://pastebin.com/2jcT937v

Comment: Question: What version of WP are you using? I'm asking as the K2 Theme hasn't had any updates since far more than a year (afaik).

Comment: "Use the wp_enqueue_scripts action to call this function, or admin_enqueue_scripts to call it on the admin side." -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Other then using `wp_enqueue_scripts` like suggested already, make sure you are not after a `?>` (php closing tag) or better yet post all of your code for us to see.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see a live link to the site in question.

Comment: Already flagged for mods to move it SO as it seems to be a plain JS-Error _inside_ the JS file.

Answer (score 0):

First: why are you using the [over two years old K2 Theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/k2)?

(Just to rule out Theme issues: switch to Twenty Eleven, and try to enqueue your script; verify whether the script does or does not get enqueued.)

Second: try hooking into `wp_enqueue_scripts`, rather than into `init`.

#### Edit

From your live link source, we can see that your script **is being enqueued**:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://gregmathes.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://gregmathes.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/fadetoblackgreg.js?ver=3.3.1'></script>
```

The problem, then, is not with the script *enqueueing*, but more likely, with the script itself.

Note: with the exception of WordPress requiring jQuery scripts to use [no-conflict syntax](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers), script debugging is generally out of scope for WPSE.

Comment: Is there a rule against using old themes? I bought my computer 2 years ago, my operating system is older than that. By switch, do you mean I have to activate Twenty Eleven?

Comment: "***Is there a rule against using old themes?***" - Of course not; however, the older a Theme is, the less-likely it is to conform to current best practices, or to support the most current features. WordPress Theme functionality has changed and improved a *great deal* since January 2010 when K2 was last updated, so it is very likely that the Theme could be contributing to your issues. "***By switch, do you mean I have to activate Twenty Eleven?***" - Yes; for the purposes of trouble-shooting, I'm asking you to switch Themes temporarily.

Comment: Switching to Twenty Eleven didn't fix anything, neither did calling wp_enqueue_scripts in lieu of init.

Comment: When you switched to Twenty Eleven, how did you attempt to enqueue your custom script?

Comment: I pasted the same bit of code in the functions.php file that I had in the K2 functions.php file. Then I uploaded the .js file into the twenty eleven folder of my wp-content/themes/twentyeleven folder and into the js subfolder there.

Comment: Am I supposed to be calling the .js file or functions inside it or the enqueue action somewhere else?

Comment: A live link would be especially helpful here, so that we can see what scripts *are* and *are not* being enqueued.

Comment: See edited answer. Your script **IS being enqueued by WordPress**.

Comment: Ok, changing from init to to enqueue action makes it such that the script won't load in admin or outside admin. The errata text seen at the top of the pages I believe was leftover text from other attempts to locate the error. I'll try to find what the problem is with the javascript.

Comment: "*Ok, changing from init to to enqueue action makes it such that the script won't load in admin or outside admin.*" - But the script *is* loading; that is, it is being output properly in the document head. So, I don't understand what you mean here.

Comment: Yes, the script IS loading outside the admin panel after changing the the action from init. It used to properly load inside the admin panel, performing the function of the js file. After changing the action call, the script now loads, but no longer performs the function anywhere.